# Which Words Are Part of a Free Basis of $F_n$?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

Start with a free group on $n$ generators, $F=\langle a_1,\ldots, a_n\rangle$. If I write a word, $w$, in these generators, is there an efficient algorithm to determine whether or not $w$ can be extended to a free basis of $F$?

I have some comments and partial results, but no efficient algorithm.

1. If any letter appears only once (and raised to the first power), then we can extend the word to a basis (just take the rest of the basis as the other generators). This is not necessary as $c^2bcabab$ can be extended to a basis of $F_3$.
2. If the word is part of a basis, then the projection to the abelianization must be a primitive vector. Another way to say this is that if the vector in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with the $i$-th entry equal to the sum of the exponents of $a_i$ in $w$ must not be a $\mathbb{Z}$-multiple of another vector in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. This is not sufficient because $a^2b^2a$ is not part of a basis of $F_2$.

Edit:
Given a group $H=\langle w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_k\rangle\leq F_n$, there is an algorithm, due to Stallings, to determine a free basis for $H$. A (terribly inefficient) algorithm is to list all possible bases formed out of reduced words of length less than $w$, and running Stallings' algorithm on each one. I'm asking for an algorithm that can be reasonably implemented.

Comment: Related: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504401v2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $F$ is a free group and $a$ and $b$ are two elements of $F$, it is decidable whether there is an automorphism of $F$ which maps $a$ to $b$. See *Combinatorial Group Theory* by Roger C. Lyndon, Paul E. Schupp, Proposition I.4.19.

This implies, in particular, that it is decidable whether an element of $F$ is part of a basis.

Comment: I know it's decidable. I'm asking for an algorithm. And one that isn't "enumerate all possible bases formed of words of length less than $w$ and run Stallings' algorithm on each one."

Comment: Well, the book proves this by exhibiting an algorithm...

Comment: In any case, if you knew that there is an algorithm you should have probably phrased your question in a form different to «is there is a effective algorithm...» for then you already knew the answer!

Comment: I asked for an "effective" algorithm, which I usually interpret as not brute force.

Comment: Well, efficient is a more appropriate term for that.

Comment: Fair enough. I made an edit to the question to reflect this.

Comment: The algorithm is usually called the *Whitehead Algorithm*, and there is a lot of literature about it. I noticed that one of the articles, by Gersten, does describe it as an "effective" algorithm, so perhaps that is an appropriate description!

Comment: Roughly speaking, I would interpret "effective algorithm" as meaning one that gives useful results in reasonable time on many examples, whereas an "efficient" algorithm is one for which good complexity estimates can be proved - it is often used as being almost equivalent to polynomial time.

Comment: Mariano, I edited your Lyndon and Schupp Proposition reference - Lyndon and Schupp start counting anew with each chapter, so although there is probably only one "Proposition 4.19", there are, for example, three "Proposition 2.1"s...